# How do I take parts of a file name and put it in a bash array?

Tags: bash

I have a bunch of file names as follows:
SRR1993270_assembly.fna
SRR1993271_assembly.fna
etc. There are 10 such files.

I want to create a bash array with just the SRR IDS, i.e., (SRR1993270, SRR1993271, ...)

How do I do this?

I first tried

```
assemblies="$(basename -s _assembly.fna *.fna)"
```

When I perform

```
echo $assemblies
```

it echoes the files as desired.

But when I try to display the names separately,

```
echo ${assemblies[1]}
```

it shows the entire file name

This has me quite confused and would appreciate some clarity.

Comment: Using bash parameter expansion:  `f="SRR1993270_assembly.fna"; echo "${f%%_*}"`.  Should just print the SRR1993270 of the filename.

Comment: `assemblies` in your code is not an array, so `${assemblies[1]}` doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 5):

> assemblies="$(basename -s _assembly.fna *.fna)"

Is not an [array](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html) it is assigning [Command Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) in a variable.

---

One approach:

```
##: Save the files ending in .fna in an array named files
files=(*.fna)
```

```
##: Or using `_assembly.fna`
files=(*_assembly.fna)
```

---

> I want to create a bash array with just the SRR IDS, i.e., (SRR1993270, SRR1993271, ...)

With [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) Something like this:

```
##: Remove the `_` and the rest of the file name using Parameter
##: Expansion and save it an array named `ids`
ids=("${files[@]%%_*}")
```

- One way to check the value of the array

```
declare -p ids
```

- With echo

```
echo "${ids[@]}"
```

---

Using `mapfile` aka `readarray` which is a `bash4+` feature and [Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html), with your `basename` approach.

```
mapfile -t assemblies < <(basename -s _assembly.fna *.fna)
```

One way to check the value of the array

```
 declare -p assemblies
```

---

- Might need to use [nullglob](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#nullglob)
- See [Check if a directory is empty](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/004)

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually creating an array, you're creating a single string when you call `"$(basename ...)"`

If your filenames have no spaces in the base, you can get an array out by encasing the whole thing in parentheses

i.e.

```
$ assemblies=($(basename -s _assembly.fna *.fna))
$ echo ${assemblies[2]} # SRR1993272
```

As noted in the comments, if there are filenames with spaces or tabs in them the above method will break. In that case you can build up the array with a for loop.

i.e

```
$ for i in {0..9}; do touch SRR\ 199327$i_assembly.fna; done # make sample filenames
$ assemblies=()
$ for f in SRR\ 199327*; do assemblies+=("$(basename -s _assembly.fna $)"); done
$ echo ${assemblies[1]} # SRR 1993271
```